# Getting multiple audio clips to same level

Tags: audio, audacity, ableton-live

I am working on a project that involves using a lot of found audio clips (some new, some very old archival and poor quality etc).

I am trying to figure out a way to have all audio clips to be of a similar quality (if this is possible) and play at a similar volume?

I have use of both audacity and ableton...any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Probably better asked on Sound Engineering.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is commonly called normalization. There are several tools that can do it, including [commandline](https://superuser.com/questions/23156/linux-audio-tools-is-there-a-way-to-normalize-the-volume-of-ogg-files) tools and also audacity.

You'll find the tool in audacity under Effect > Normalize...

You can select multiple audio tracks.

Comment: Thanks Lykos...I'll give this a try. Just to be clear if I have two different audio tracks (mp3) of different quality and volumes, if I put to them together into a new track and apply normalize effect, I can have them play at same level?

Comment: @heroZero I suppose, I have never used audacity for normalization though. https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/normalize.html says it should work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using a limiter and/or a compressor on your track. Have a look in the Live effect reference for more info on these: https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-audio-effect-reference/

The results will not be as good as applying normalization by hand, but it will be a lot quicker.